# Report Viewer limitation

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report-viewer2012

I have a ReportViewer(C#, asp.net 4.5).

My query returns over 700'000 rows of data but it takes forever for the report viewer to show(it does not show, I think report viewer rendering is extremely slow).

Is there a limitation for the report viewer data?

Has Anyone here have experience of showing several tens of thousands of pages on the ReportViewer?

Comment: Only the current page is rendered by Reporting Services, not all at once.  That aside, why on earth are you trying to show 700,000 rows of data on a report?

Comment: Your best bet with extremely large reports like that is to schedule them to be exported to CSV. Creating Excel files of that size will often exceed both timeouts and file size limitations. Rendering them in a viewer also requires a lot of overhead.

Comment: @iamdave  it's not me who designed this.  I'm just being asked to re-write the code in the new version of.NET. Old version for this large dataset does not work which I'm not surprised.